# String return function redirect to other page in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: string, function, redirect, output

I have one function that return string value from that function. Here below shown my some code

```
<code>
public string MainPane()
{
 if (Request.Cookies["Cookie"] != null)
 {
  try
  {
    //DO Something code here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }
  return("");
}
else
{
  //I need to redirect from here when cookie value is null
}
</code>
```

Thanks,

Nirav Parikh

---

This is my asp.net MVC application so

```
Response.Redirect("Index");
```

this feature not available. I had tried

```
RedirectToAction("Action Name","Controller Name");
```

but function return string value and RedirectToAction not return string.

Thanks, Nirav

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score -1):

You can use :

```
Response.Redirect("Index");
```

It will redirect you without you needing to return an ActionResult.